# Setting a password lock policy on Android while Allowing Fingerprint Unlock

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, device-management

I have a device admin application that restricts the users to set a password lock using DevicePolicyManager class. I want the users to still be able to unlock the device using their fingerprint. Is there a way to do so?